# Any way to detect android device type (phone/pad) in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox-android

The userAgent of Chrome and Edge, both contains a 'Mobile' word on android phone.
And don't contains it on android pad.

But the Firefox userAgent on phone is exactly alike it on pad.

So, is there any accurate way to detect the android device type for Firefox?

Comment: `navigator.platform ` or `navigator.oscpu` ..?

Comment: Checked on devices, firefox navigator is same both on phone and pad. @Teemu

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do that is detect with size of device because tablets are basically bigger then phones

hope something like this could help :

```
let isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 760px)").matches;
if (isMobile) {
    //Conditional script here
}
```

Comment: But the horizontal width of phone is bigger than vertical pad width.